# Как не кешировать переменные IPython?

Tags: python, ipython, jupyter-notebook

При первом запуске блока IPython с переменной со словарём, например:

```
In[7]: test_dict = {'key_1': 1.8529757571664867,
                    'key_2': 1.551270403313663,
                    'key_3': 0.8213399558579995}
```

и функцией:

```
In[8]: def rename_keys(inp_dict, add):
           for k, v in sorted(inp_dict.items()):
               inp_dict[k + add] = inp_dict.pop(k)
           return inp_dict

In[9]: rename_keys(test_dict, '_W')
```

IPython выведет ожидаемый результат:

```
Out[9]: {'key_1_W': 1.8529757571664867,
         'key_2_W': 1.551270403313663,
         'key_3_W': 0.8213399558579995}
```

Но, если я например захотел изменить окончание с "_W" на "_K", то при изменении и повторном прогоне блока я получу старую переменную с уже изменённым окончанием + новым окончанием:

```
In[10]: rename_keys(test_dict, '_K')

Out[10]: {'key_1_W_K': 1.8529757571664867,
          'key_2_W_K': 1.551270403313663,
          'key_3_W_K': 0.8213399558579995}
```

Как заставить блокнот запускать код с нуля?

> UPD: Конечно, логично и очевидно, что последующие вызовы подразумевают уже изменённый объект, но можно ли сделать так, чтобы при изменении именно в `In[9]` я имел вывод `Out[9]`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
# новый объект
print({'%s_W' % k: test_dict[k] for k in test_dict})
print({'%s_K' % k: test_dict[k] for k in test_dict})

# Или, если возвращать тот же объект
def rename_keys(inp_dict):
    dt = inp_dict.copy()
    while True:
        add = yield
        inp_dict.clear()
        inp_dict.update({k + add: dt[k] for k in dt})
        yield inp_dict

r = rename_keys(test_dict)
next(r)
print(r.send('_W'))
next(r)
print(r.send('_K'))
```

Comment: +1 за вариант, который ввод неизменяет